# Keyup event and keyboard

Tags: keyup

The keyup event used in various programming framework is raised from keyboard? Is the circuit of keyboard to generate the event or the event is deducted by operating system?

Comment: Modern keyboards talk via USB or Bluetooth-there's no direct connection to the machine's interrupt circuitry. Even before it was a serial protocol initiated by the processor in the keyboard. Before that the machine itself did its own matrix scanning to detect key presses. Only rarely do key presses generate an interrupt on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard operations are electronically processed by circuitry inside the device. So every action emits interrupt, which is processed by top-level system, like the OS. So various frameworks are subscribed to the events generated by it. 
Further details on how interrupt system works can be found at
http://en.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/devices.html

Comment: If I am not wrong, there is an interrupt for keydown and one for keyup, right?

Comment: You are right. Generally speaking every hardware event (generated by keyboard, or other devices) is processed by the corresponding drivers, and drivers generate software events, that can be used by operating system and applications.